# Why my Magento Cloud suddenly show DI generation issue?

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud, message-queue

I didn't deploy anything for 1 month on my Magento Cloud, but I started to see this error message in my `var/log` folder.

```
[2022-03-27 00:16:06] report.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /app/avycv8hfbkyv1/generated/code/Amasty/Gdpr/Model/Notification/Notifier/AnonymizationNotifier/.
Class Amasty\Gdpr\Model\Notification\Notifier\AnonymizationNotifier\Proxy generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. [] []
#25 /app/avycv8hfbkyv1/generated/code/Magento/MessageQueue/Console/StartConsumerCommand/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\MessageQueue\Console\StartConsumerCommand\Interceptor->___callPlugins('run', Array, Array)
#26 /app/avycv8hfbkyv1/generated/code/Magento/MessageQueue/Console/StartConsumerCommand/Proxy.php(143): Magento\MessageQueue\Console\StartConsumerCommand\Interceptor->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /app/avycv8hfbkyv1/generated/code/Magento/MessageQueue/Console/StartConsumerCommand/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\MessageQueue\Console\StartConsumerCommand\Interceptor->___callPlugins('run', Array, Array)
#26 /app/avycv8hfbkyv1/generated/code/Magento/MessageQueue/Console/StartConsumerCommand/Proxy.php(143): Magento\MessageQueue\Console\StartConsumerCommand\Interceptor->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I know I'm not supposed to run the `setup:di:compile` on Magento Cloud and I didn't, but why did it suddenly appear?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just enabled or configured a new option related to GDPR Anonymization, which triggered this issue.

Try these steps:

- Check your RabbitMQ queue and connection.
- Recompile your Magento using Magento Cloud auto deploy.
- Try disabling your module, if it's the issue, you might have to update your module or refactor it.

Try to simulate the same issue using this command:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all
```

Answer (score 0):

All autogenerated proxy classes MUST be defined in di.xml to be properly generated.
Please check if there is any proxy that is defined in PHP code directly, and move it to di

Comment: Hi KAndy, the proxy was defined via di.xml inside the Amasty module, and we didn't have any deployment to customize it since the issue appeared.